# Take a picture from google streetview

Tags: google-maps, image-processing, google-street-view

Is it possible to embed streetview for an address. Then user will move around in streetview with zoom, pan etc and finally can we provide user a button which will capture the image and send to an application. Alternatively, if it is not possible to use the button and capture an image of what the user sees then, we can we take a streetview link from the user like [this one](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&q=RG1+4RT&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Reading+RG1+4RT,+United+Kingdom&layer=c&cbll=51.452259,-0.960783&panoid=djaBqPT_T2_Au0weAUi4Ow&cbp=12,68.41,,0,2.1&ll=51.452259,-0.960783&spn=0.000829,0.002411&z=19) and then can we get the image on php similar to what is shown in flash?

The whole idea is to be able to get what user sees on streetview as an image to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [StreetView.py](http://code.google.com/p/adqmisc/source/browse/trunk/streetview/StreetView.py) This python script parses all panorama information.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can use iecapt.exe which will capture a particular div area.
you can check on the following link
 [capturing webpage using iecapt](http://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/capture-web-page-as-image-using-asp-net/)